# Publish Entire Meter.users collection

Tags: meteor

I am trying to publish all of the Meteor.users to a `People` collection. My publish function looks just like the one out of docs except I am not specifying the fields to publish:

```
Meteor.publish("people", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    console.log(Meteor.users.find({}).count());
    return Meteor.users.find();
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

The `console.log` prints `80` so I know that there are users. However when I query on my client, `People.find().count()` it returns `0`. What am I doing wrong thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually very possible to publish users to a different collection on the client side. But you'll have to get your hands dirty and use the low-level observe and publication APIs. For example:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // note this is a client-only collection
  People = new Mongo.Collection('people');

  Meteor.subscribe('people', function() {
    // this function will run after the publication calls `sub.ready()`
    console.log(People.find().count()); // 3
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // create some dummy users for this example
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({username: 'foobar', password: 'foobar'});
    Accounts.createUser({username: 'bazqux', password: 'foobar'});
    Accounts.createUser({username: 'bonker', password: 'foobar'});
  }

  Meteor.publish('people', function() {
    var sub = this;

    // get a cursor for all Meteor.users documents
    // only include specified fields so private user data doesn't get published
    var userCursor = Meteor.users.find({}, {
      fields: {
        username: 1,
        profile: 1
      }
    });

    // observe changes to the cursor and propagate them to the client,
    // specifying that they should go to a collection with the name 'people'
    var userHandle = userCursor.observeChanges({
      added: function(id, user) {
        sub.added('people', id, user);
      },
      changed: function(id, fields) {
        sub.changed('people', id, fields);
      },
      removed: function(id) {
        sub.removed('people', id);
      }
    });

    // tell the client that the initial subscription snapshot has been sent.
    sub.ready();

    // stop observing changes to the cursor when the client stops the subscription
    sub.onStop(function() {
      userHandle.stop();
    });
  });
}
```

Note that I am only publishing the `username` and `profile` fields here: you *do not* want to publish entire user documents as it will send down private information such as their password hash, 3rd party service information, etc.

Notice that you can use this method to separate published users into different arbitrarily-named client-side collections, too. You might have an `AdminUsers` collection, a `BannedUsers` collection, etc. Then you can selectively publish documents from the same MongoDB (server) collection to different Minimongo (client) collections.

EDIT: I realized there is an undocumented Meteor feature called `Mongo.Collection._publishCursor` which does most of the stuff inside the publish function in my example. So you can actually rewrite that publication like this and it will work exactly the same, publishing `Meteor.users` documents to a client-side `'people'` collection:

```js
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
  var userCursor = Meteor.users.find({}, {
    fields: {
      username: 1,
      profile: 1
    }
  });

  // this automatically observes the cursor for changes,
  // publishes added/changed/removed messages to the 'people' collection,
  // and stops the observer when the subscription stops
  Mongo.Collection._publishCursor(userCursor, this, 'people');

  this.ready();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a Collection called `People`?  Just because your publish function is named "people" doesn't mean that there is a meteor collection called `People`.

Sounds to me like you need to either define a mongo collection called People and populate it, or you should query the Meteor.users collection from the client -- since you are returning `Meteor.users.find()`.

Comment: I think if he would delete the else part in the publish-function and would create a subscription to 'people' on the client he could query Meteor.users. But the question was how to publish all of the Meteor.users to a People collection. Publishing something to a collection makes no sense.

Comment: @DanielBudick Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but meteor allows you to publish documents to specific collections using `observeChanges` and calls to the `this.added()`, `this.changed()`, and `this.removed()` methods, rather than returning a cursor. This is demonstrated in an example in the docs under [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish). In the example the publication sends documents to a collection on the client called `counts` - even though this collection does not exist on the server. Using the same method, you could publish user documents to a `people` collection.

Comment: The publish function publishes a set of documents. These documents are stored in a client side collection. If the set of documents changes (added, removed or changed) the client side collection is updated. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @DanielBudick Specifically what I mean is that DDP and therefore Meteor sends subscription updates to an arbitrarily named client-side collection. The client only knows what document belongs to what collection because the server tells it the name of the collection inside the added/changed/removed DDP message. Inside a Meteor publication, you can explicitly send these added/changed/removed messages with any arbitrary string for the collection name, and the client will add it to that collection if its defined. So you are always "publishing something to a collection". See my answer in this thread

Comment: I did see your answer and I think I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielBudick I'd also recommend reading the [DDP specification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) as it will give you some more insight into how Meteor works. DDP is actually a surprisingly simple and short protocol!